# How to find almost similar records in sql?

Tags: sql, algorithm, postgresql, similarity

This is the search record:

```
A = {
    field1: value1,
    field2: value2,
    ...
    fieldN: valueN
}
```

I have many such records in the database.

Other record (B) almost matches record A if even N-M fields in these records are equal. This is the example, M=2:

```
B = {
    field1: OTHER_value1,
    field2: OTHER_value2,
    field3: value3,
    ...
    fieldN: valueN
}
```

If can be any fields, not only the first.

I can make the very big combinatorial sql query, but may be there is more beautiful solution.

P.S.: My database is PostgreSQL.

Comment: Two questions: 1. Do you have control over the data structure? and 2. Is there significance in the ordering of the field values in a record?

Comment: What is the data type of the values?

Comment: 1. Yes, this is my data scructures, I have control.  2. Order doesn't matter. But - it is columns! I should use indexes. 3. strings.

Answer (score 3):

Such a search criteria won't be able to make use of any indexes, but it can be done...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE
  N-M <= CASE WHEN yourTable.field1 = searchValue1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       + CASE WHEN yourTable.field2 = searchValue2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       + CASE WHEN yourTable.field3 = searchValue3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       ...
       + CASE WHEN yourTable.fieldN = searchValueN THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Similarly, if your search criteria is in another table...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  yourTable
INNER JOIN
  search
    ON N-M <= CASE WHEN yourTable.field1 = search.field1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            + CASE WHEN yourTable.field2 = search.field2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            + CASE WHEN yourTable.field3 = search.field3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            ...
            + CASE WHEN yourTable.fieldN = search.fieldN THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

*(You need to populate the value of `N-M`yourself)*

***EDIT:***

A more long winded approach, that can make *some* use of indexes...

```
SELECT
    id,  -- your table would need to have a primary key / identity column
    MAX(field1)   AS field1,
    MAX(field2)   AS field2,
    MAX(field3)   AS field3,
    ...
    MAX(fieldN)   AS fieldN
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE field1 = searchValue1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE field2 = searchValue2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE field3 = searchValue3
    ...
    SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE fieldN = searchValueN
)
    AS unioned_seeks
GROUP BY
    id
HAVING
    COUNT(*) >= N-M
```

Where you have an index on each field individually, and where you expect a relatively low number of matches for each field this ***might*** outperform the first option, at the expense of very repetitious code.

Answer (score 3):

I would do this using `is not distinct from` to handle `NULL` values.

You can also use Postgres short-hand to simplify the logic.  One way is:

```
where ( (a.field1 is not distinct from b.field1)::int +
        (a.field2 is not distinct from b.field2)::int +
        . . .
        (a.fieldn is not distinct from b.fieldn)::int +
      ) >= N - M
```

I think this is easier to express only in terms of `M`.  So, only look at the fields that are different:

```
where ( (a.field1 is distinct from b.field1)::int +
        (a.field2 is distinct from b.field2)::int +
        . . .
        (a.fieldn is distinct from b.fieldn)::int +
      ) <= M
```

Doing this with your data requires a `cross join` which is quite expensive.

Comment: On the assumption that the Op *wants* `NULL` to equate to `NULL`, which would be non-standard behaviour in SQL?

Comment: @MatBailie . . . When looking for similar records in different tables, I usually want `NULL` values to be considered equivalent.