# How to find almost similar records in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, algorithm, similarity

This is the search record:

```
A = {
    field1: value1,
    field2: value2,
    ...
    fieldN: valueN
}
```

I have many such records in the database.

Other record (B) almost matches record A if even N-M fields in these records are equal. This is the example, M=2:

```
B = {
    field1: OTHER_value1,
    field2: OTHER_value2,
    field3: value3,
    ...
    fieldN: valueN
}
```

It can be any fields, not only the first.

P.S.: I have copied the same query for postgresql - [How to find almost similar records in sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47877071/how-to-find-almost-similar-records-in-sql) and now I want to do this with mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
db.col.aggregate(
   [
      {
            $addFields:
            {
                nonMatchCount: 0
            }
      },

      {
            $addFields: {
             nonMatchCount: 
               {
                 $cond: [{$eq: ['$field1', 'OTHER_value1']}, '$nonMatchCount', {$sum: ['$nonMatchCount', 1]}]
               }
           }
      },

      {
            $addFields: {
             nonMatchCount: 
               {
                 $cond: [{$eq: ['$field2', 'OTHER_value2']}, '$nonMatchCount', {$sum: ['$nonMatchCount', 1]}]
               }
           }
      },

      {
            $addFields: {
             nonMatchCount: 
               {
                 $cond: [{$eq: ['$field3', 'value3']}, '$nonMatchCount', {$sum: ['$nonMatchCount', 1]}]
               }
           }
      },

      ...

      {
            $addFields: {
             nonMatchCount: 
               {
                 $cond: [{$eq: ['$fieldN', 'valueN']}, '$nonMatchCount', {$sum: ['$nonMatchCount', 1]}]
               }
           }
      },      

        {$match: { nonMatchCount: {$lte: 2}}}
   ]
);
```